# When mouseleave inside the slideffect time the text stays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My intention is when i hover over the #portfolioitem1 div a text slides up and when i leave the text goes away again.
The code works but if i hover over the div and move away instantly(eg 0.3 sec) when the slideDown effect is working.

Then the text does not go away and stays there.
And i have to hover over it again and remove my mous after 0.3 seconds for it to work.

Anyone a idea?

Javascript

```
 $('#text').hide();
 $('#portfolioitem1').hover(function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E95850');
    $('#text').slideDown(300);
});
$('#portfolioitem1').mouseleave(function (){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#999999');
    $('#text').hide();
});
```

html

```
 <div id="portfolioitem1"><div id="text">vgregvre</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stopping the animation before you hide the div, because even after you hide the div the animation will still continue to show the div.

```
$('#text').stop(false,false).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t57MT/

Comment: Worked perfectly Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#text').hide();
$('#portfolioitem1')
  .hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#E95850');
    $('#text').slideDown(300);
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#999999');
    $('#text').hide();
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/j33dm/)**